# can't get json data, giving Cors or callback error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cors

I'm trying to get some JSON data from a REST API, but when I call it cia an AJAX request with `dataType` param as `jsonp` it gives me an error that the jQuery 'callback was not called'. This is the error message:

> Error: Status: parsererror Message: Error: jQuery2130732580496231094_1429605569499 was not called

So, if I try to make this request without `jsonp`, using JSON as the `dataType`, it gives me another error about the CORS:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I know this is an idiot question, but I've read about CORS and just don't get where to put it's params to enable it. For me, the right is to use the first method that I've used, but after looking for an answer for that problem, I just don't understand anything. If someday I could understand where to put the CORS I should be use to make the request as another way.

So they are my questions, here is my code:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'eztvapi.re/shows/1';, 
    type: 'GET', 
    dataType: 'jsonp', 
    crossDomain: true, 
    success: function(data) { 
        //data = JSON.parse(data); 
        console.log(data); 
    }, 
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        console.log("Error: Status: " + textStatus + " Message: " + errorThrown); 
    } 
});
```

This are my headers request from the console:

```
    Remote Address:216.58.222.12:443
Request URL:http://eztvapi.re/shows/1?callback=jQuery213010618196451105177_1429606458524&_=1429606458525
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Response Headers
cache-control:private
content-encoding:gzip
content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8
date:Tue, 21 Apr 2015 08:54:22 GMT
etag:W/"0hnqCn40L98JLmwY2UfUlg=="
server:nginx
status:200
vary:Accept-Encoding
via:1.1 Chrome-Compression-Proxy
x-powered-by:Express
x-response-time:32ms
x-served-by:us-la3
Request Headers
:authority:eztvapi.re
:method:GET
:path:/shows/1?callback=jQuery213010618196451105177_1429606458524&_=1429606458525
:scheme:http
accept:*/*
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
accept-language:pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
chrome-proxy:ps=1429584828-1395746459-275388119-220935266, sid=a259cd2eeb457c7a40ff6367868ef723, c=win, b=2311, p=90
user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
callback:jQuery213010618196451105177_1429606458524
_:1429606458525
```

And this are the json object that the request returns, BUT IT ONLY APPEARS ON THE CONSOLE NETWORK PART:

```
 0: {_id: "tt0944947",…}
1: {_id: "tt0903747",…}
2: {_id: "tt0898266",…}
3: {_id: "tt1520211",…}
4: {_id: "tt0773262",…}
5: {_id: "tt0460649",…}
6: {_id: "tt1475582",…}
7: {_id: "tt2193021",…}
8: {_id: "tt1796960",…}
9: {_id: "tt1119644",…}
10: {_id: "tt0411008",…}
```

I've done recently a lot of requests for another rests,so i think the client's side is correctly. This is a new server that i'm testing my requests, but this is not my server domain, this belows to a popular rest server and i believe that supports json call. What is funny and i've asking myself since i've start with this new one is the response that i'm getting. You can see that server answers my request with the correctly data, but i can't get the data to my javascript, to print it or process it.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Post the code to your attempts, and preferably some details about the REST API as well.

Comment: Could you post some code ? The way you are making JSONP request ?

Comment: $.ajax({
  url: 'http://eztvapi.re/shows/1',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  crossDomain:true,
  success:function(data){
   console.log(data);
  },
  error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   console.log("Error: Status: "+textStatus+" Message: "+errorThrown);
       }
 });                                                                                                                       This is my first try, as dataType jsonp, but if i took it off or put without jsonp it give me the cors error.

Comment: Are you sure that the REST API you're calling supports the JSONP format? From the first error message it sounds like it's not returning you a callback parameter. From your second error message it does not support CORS either (which is not something you can change - it's done on the server). If both of these cases are true then you cannot request data from this API in JavaScript - you need to use a server-side call.

Comment: Your edits don't actually tell us anything we couldn't already infer: As per my answer: The server you are making the request to doesn't support JSONP and isn't configured to give you permission to access the data with CORS.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Status: parsererror Message: Error: jQuery2130732580496231094_1429605569499 was not called

The server you are requesting data from has to support JSONP in order for you to make a successful JSONP request to it.

See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) on the subject for details of how to do that.

> I've read about CORS and just don't get where to put it's params to enable it.

In the HTTP response headers of the service you are making the request to.

e.g. Your page on `example.com` wants to use JS to get data from `example.net`. Therefore `example.net` has to tell the user's browser that `example.com` is allowed access to the data.

Answer (score 0):

To enable CORS requests, you have to allow this type of request from your server part and create a request from your client which will be allow to get cors resources : 
Only use GET, HEAD or POST and content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain.

Your client part seems to be correct, I think you have to deal with the server to allow this type of request.
you can have more informations [here](http://enable-cors.org/resources.html)

Comment: There is no need to explicitly add any specific request headers to use CORS. The browser will do that automatically.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the mistake I edit my post to reflect your correction

Comment: CORS does not restrict HTTP method or Content-Type.  It is possible to set restrictions like that on the server, but it is not common.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after a couple of days studying this problem i've solved this. Not from the most easy way, but... solved :D

I wrote an app with express and request on NodeJs, and using the request it returned me all the json object. Now i could just send it to my javascript var with the express.

Thanks for all the replies guys! Peace.